# How to sort dict of dicts by keys?

Tags: python, dictionary, key, sorting

I have a dict, that looks like:

```
channels = {
'24': {'type': 'plain', 'table_name': 'channel.items.AuctionChannel'}, 
'26': {'type': 'plain', 'table_name': 'channel.gm.DeleteAvatarChannel'}, 
'27': {'type': 'plain', 'table_name': 'channel.gm.AvatarMoneyChannel'}, 
'20': {'type': 'plain', 'table_name': 'channel.gm.AvatarMoneyAssertChannel'}, 
'21': {'type': 'plain', 'table_name': 'channel.gm.AvatarKillMobComplexChannel'}, 
'22': {'type': 'plain', 'table_name': 'channel.gm.DistributionMarkChannel'}, 
'23': {'type': 'plain', 'table_name': 'channel.gm.MailChannel'}
}
```

i want to sort it by keys('24','26','27', etc...), it should be like:

```
channels = {
'20': {'type': 'plain', 'table_name': 'channel.gm.AvatarMoneyAssertChannel'}, 
'21': {'type': 'merged', 'table_name': 'channel.gm.AvatarKillMobComplexChannel'}, 
'22': {'type': 'plain', 'table_name': 'channel.gm.DistributionMarkChannel'}, 
'23': {'type': 'plain', 'table_name': 'channel.gm.MailChannel'}
'24': {'type': 'merged', 'table_name': 'channel.items.AuctionChannel'}, 
'26': {'type': 'plain', 'table_name': 'channel.gm.DeleteAvatarChannel'}, 
'27': {'type': 'plain', 'table_name': 'channel.gm.AvatarMoneyChannel'}, 
}
```

I have read articles, but i don't understand how to sort by keys of main dict.

Comment: A `dict` cannot be sorted. Its items are stored in "random" order (depends on implementation of dict). So, you have to use `collections.OrderedDict`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a `dict` is a mapping, keys are not ordered. this is due to the way the `dict()` type is implemented: keys are hashed (using the `hash()` builtin function) and the order you observe derives from this hash.

you will need an ordered dict for the dictionary to keep its ordering and to allow you to sort the keys. the [`collections.OrderedDict`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html) type is the builtin ordered dict for python 3.x.

here is an example of sorting your data:

```
import collections

channels = {
'24': {'type': 'plain', 'table_name': 'channel.items.AuctionChannel'}, 
'26': {'type': 'plain', 'table_name': 'channel.gm.DeleteAvatarChannel'}, 
'27': {'type': 'plain', 'table_name': 'channel.gm.AvatarMoneyChannel'}, 
'20': {'type': 'plain', 'table_name': 'channel.gm.AvatarMoneyAssertChannel'}, 
'21': {'type': 'plain', 'table_name': 'channel.gm.AvatarKillMobComplexChannel'}, 
'22': {'type': 'plain', 'table_name': 'channel.gm.DistributionMarkChannel'}, 
'23': {'type': 'plain', 'table_name': 'channel.gm.MailChannel'}
}

channels = collection.OrderedDict(sorted(channels.items(), key=lambda item: item[0]))
for key,value in channels.items():
    print(key, ':', value)
```

Answer (score 6):

Dicts are not sorted/ordered. If you are using python 2.7 you can use an OrderedDict though.

Answer (score 5):

Standard dict is not sorted. You can however iterate over its keys and values in a sorted order:

```
for channelName, channelValue in sorted(channels.items()):
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

A dict is unsorted. But if you want to iterate in the described manner, you can do it as follows:

```
for key in sorted(channels):
    print key
```

Results in:

```
20
21
22
23
24
26
27
```

Or use collections.OrderedDict.

Comment: this is only keys, but i want to have sorted keys and values

Comment: my idea was that you can access the values in channels simply with 'channels[key]'

Answer (score 0):

A dict doesn't have its keys in a order, the order is not guaranteed. If you want to create a list of dictionaries you'll lose the key info.

If you need sorted iterations you can use

```
for key in sorted(dict):
    ....
```

Answer (score 0):

```
result=collections.OrderedDict(sorted(your_dict.items()))
```

Comment: Instead of `lambda x:x[0]` you could use `operator.itemgetter(0)`

Comment: @ThiefMaster: Why would I use more imports? How is this good? In any case, the lambda thing wasn't required, so I removed it.

Comment: The `itemgetter` version is faster. And why would you _not_ want more imports?

Comment: I don't have against before imports, i want to see different variants.

Answer (score 0):

try with something like:

```
print [ {i: channels[i] } for  i in sorted(channels)]
```